# Get href value from content and send email via PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

**How is this possibly not ethical? The client wants an online interface to view email proposals and can then click "accept" or "reject" will will send a static email to that person, telling them if their proposal has been accepted or not.**

I'm trying to scrape an email address from the content on a page, assign that email address to a value, and then send an email via PHP with that address.

Except, the following's not working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var from_address = $('.rcmContactAddress').attr('href');
    from_address = from_address.substring(7);
    $('#to').value(from_address);
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="to" value=""></input>
```

The page (built with a Roundcube backend) will display the email message, with a button for accept or reject. Part of the page content looks like this:

```
<td class="header from">
    <span>
        <a href="mailto:emailaddress" onclick="return rcmail.command('compose','emailaddress',this)" title="emailaddress" class="rcmContactAddress">Contact Name</a>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: doesn't sound very ethical ...

Comment: What's not working? how the page looks like?

Comment: *"... what's the simplest way to send an email via mail() in PHP?"* Sounds like recursion.

Comment: How? The client wants an online interface to view email proposals and can then click "accept" or "reject" will will send a static email to that person, telling them if it's accepted or not.

Comment: You just wrote it doesn't work, what's not working? how the page looks like? what is that `rcmContactAddress` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be only one error and there are more but:

```
$('#to').value(from_address);
```

Should be:

```
$('#to').val(from_address);
```

If you can show us how the `anchor` looks like we might help you even more.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to transfer the email address to a PHP script first. You can use ajax for that. On the PHP side you will need to use the posted e-mail address and use the [mail](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Here's an example jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'yourMailSenderScript.php',
    data:{email:theEmailAddress},
    type:'post',
    cache:false
});
```